# Is there a way to change value of row based on a column range of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns (172) and many rows, and I need to change the value of one column based on a range of columns on the same dataframe.

```
COL1  COL2 COL3 ... COL17 ...
1           
2           X
3                d
4                    98
```

In the previous dataframe, I would like to change the value of COL2 to "error" if **ANY** of the columns in the range of COL3 to COL17 has any value. The expected result would be:

```
    COL1  COL2    COL3 ... COL17 ...
     1           
     2    error    X
     3    error        d
     4    error              98
```

As seen above, the first row gets no error because there's no values between COL3 and COL17, but the other rows get error in COL2 since there are values in either COL3, COL17 or any column in between those 2.

I know I can achieve this with an `ifelse()`, but the number of rows I need to check is fairly large (The range is approximately of 50 columns) so the `ifelse()` statement would be awful, plus, I don't think it would be very efficient.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `paste` the column values and then check for empty values with an `ifelse`:

```
#Creating a sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(1:4), Col2 = c("","","",""), Col3 = c("", "X", "", ""), Col4 = c("", "", "D", ""), Col5 = c("","", "", 98))
df
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1    1                    
2    2         X          
3    3              D     
4    4                  98

#pasting the column values and adding "error" if the paste is not empty
df$Col2 <- ifelse(do.call(paste, c(df[c(3:5)], sep="")) == "", "ok", "error")
df
  Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1    1    ok               
2    2 error    X          
3    3 error         D     
4    4 error             98
```